# How to make an embedded YouTube video continuously replay?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed

I'm sure there must be a small option or tweak which can be set or used in order to make this possible.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop), you should just be able to add the loop parameter.

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&loop=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID
```